# Element UI Button block

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I'm starting a vue js project and I decided to use [Element UI](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/button) which seams pretty nice.

The problem is I can't find in their documentation how to make a block button, which has the same width as the column where it is placed.

I would appreciate if you can point this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that vue dispatches the style/class prop to the parent element of your component.

So the following should work:

```
<el-button style="width: 100%">Default</el-button>
```

Comment: so basically I have to define the style on my own?

Comment: I've not worked with the framework but by having a quick look at the docs I couldn't find anything else. Like I said a class is ALSO dispatched to the parent so you can write a .stretch class and apply it to the buttons that need it.

Comment: I see. I'm not very happy to do this, but the solution you've shown works. Thank you :)

Comment: Just to mention it. If you're unhappy you can also wrap the button inside a new component (let's call it el-button-full) that wraps the style + the button and use this one instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by adding a full-width column in it, 
like so.

```
<el-row>
         <el-col :span="24">
             <el-button type="primary"> Your Button Here </el-button>
         </el-col>
 </el-row>
```